# Gem not installing package

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, compass-sass

So I'm trying to install a package

```
$ sudo gem install compass
```

to be specific. It installs correctly and shows up when I do a list:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chunky_png (1.2.5)
compass (0.12.2)
fssm (0.2.9)
sass (3.1.20)
```

but for some reason when I try to run compass nothing happens. It says the command is not found. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ compass
  bash: compass: command not found
```

I'm running Ubuntu if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm that there is output for `locate -r /compass.rb$`, then `echo $GEM_HOME`. You should find that `gem` doesn't know about the directory that `compass` installed to. You can either move it from its previous location into the directory specified by `GEM_HOME`, or else append that directory to the variable in your `~/.bash_rc` file. Much better, though, would be to use [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/) for managing your gems (and Rubies), as it neatly avoids this sort of issue and also allows much finer control over the whole process.

Comment: locate -r /compass.rb$ returns nothing. echo $GEM_HOME also returns nothing. How can I find where compass was installed into and whether gem is checking those directories?

Comment: Well, that was pretty much the whole point of running those commands. : ) If `locate` didn't find it, it probably means your database hasn't updated yet, but you shouldn't have to manually bother with that. Try running `locate chunky_png.rb` instead and see if the `compass` directory is there as well; it *really* should be, but let me know if it isn't and we'll go from there.

Comment: locate chunky_png.rb returns nothing =/ After some searching I did find the executables in the following directory: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin
I just don't know why it didn't automatically add it to my path...

Comment: Well, I'm glad you got it sorted, but please do consider using `rvm`. You are bound to run into another situation like this some time down the road, and it's better to have it set up before your collection grows unwieldy; of course, `rvm` would prevent that unwieldiness from ever occurring. : )

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. gem install compass returns successfully, but then I see "command not found: compass" I looked into using rvm to install compass, but I see this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758276/how-do-i-install-ruby-gems-when-using-rvm suggesting it's unnecssary. My system locates compass.rb: /home/ksk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb and $GEM_HOME: /home/ksk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327 and my path lists: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/ksk/.rvm/bin I'm unclear on what's the next thing to do?

Comment: plus one for the link to rvm

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by follwing this:

http://markushedlund.com/dev-tech/ubuntu-compass-command-not-found

The problem is concerned about the global variable PATH that is not being updated correctly when installing gem compass

Run

> echo "PATH=\$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:\$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin" >>
>   /etc/profile.d/rubygems1.8.sh

and re-login