# compass not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, sass, compass

This problem is similar to the following issues:

- [Gem not installing package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680416/gem-not-installing-package)
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-compass/+bug/1100018

but compass doesn't work.  It's not a PATH issue reported by some others.

The canonical package gave errors.

> Canonical package: `sudo apt-get install ruby-compass`

Used the gem instead:

> Gem install: `sudo gem install compass`

Console output:

> `compass --version`:
>
> `Errno::ENOENT on line 25 of
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/../compass/version.rb: No such file or
>   directory -
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/../compass/../../VERSION.yml`
>
> `compass watch`:
>
> `LoadError on line 122 of
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/../compass/configuration/data.rb: no
>   such file to load -- compass/import-once/activate`

I am not able to get compass working properly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found something that worked.

`sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo update_rubygems
sudo gem install compass`

Comment: Just a note: on ubuntu 14.04 use the package `rubygems1.9` instead

Answer (score 4):

For others having the same problem you should first remove the canonical package before installing compass with gem.

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby-compass
sudo gem install compass
```

Comment: What I had been looking for since ages! Nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this problem, I tried many recipes and no help. At last I put the missing file `VERSION.yml` manually in directory `/usr/lib/ruby`:

```
// First, create version file:
$ cd /usr/lib/ruby
$ sudo touch VERSION.yml

// Then add following content using text editor:
$ sudo vim VERSION.yml

// Use 'i' to enter insert mode, paste the text below:
---
:build:
:major: 1
:minor: 9
:patch: 1
// And use :wq + Enter to save changes.
```

This was example for version 1.9.1. You should specify your version in the file.